# SwiftUI 2 customizing GraphicalDatePickerStyle()

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, swiftui, darkmode

So I have a datePicker that I am trying to implement in Dark Mode--it has a couple graphical glitches--namely, the selected date on the calendar has a white textColor, any way I can fix this? I highlighted the problem areas in red circles, essentially I just need to be able to change the toggle color and change today's date (when it's selected) to black textColor:

```
DatePicker("", selection: self.$Time, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    .colorMultiply(Color.black)
    .colorInvert()
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .background(Color.black)
```

[image: shows what the date picker looks like]

Anyone have any ideas with how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure I understood what did you try to achieve. Standard controls support dark mode out of the box.

Comment: @Asperi 1) I know they support standard controls but I want to give the user the option to switch the color scheme in-app. All I want to do is make a Graphical datePicker that looks and functions well--I attached an image to the question so you can see what I'm talking about, the AM/PM toggle is invisible because the text is white and when you choose today as the selected day, you can't see the number because the text color is white. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations to customizing some SwiftUI elements. I tested this as well and it looks like in Dark Mode, there automatically is a white highlighted circle on the current date, which isn't customizable. I would propose the following, which uses a gray accent color when in Dark Mode:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.secondary : Color.primary)
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))

    }
```

Comment: I played around with the accentColor a bit and arrived at something I was satisfied with--thank you!